# Mongodb v4.0 Transaction, MongoError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, transactions

I've installed `MongoDB v4.0` for the most amazing feature of it **Transaction** in Nodejs with `mongodb` 3.1 as a driver.

When I try to use a transaction session I've faced this error:

```
MongoError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos.
```

What's that and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`Transactions` are undoubtedly the most exciting new feature in `MongoDB 4.0`. But unfortunately, most tools for installing and running MongoDB start a standalone server as opposed to a replica set. If you try to start a session on a standalone server, you'll get this error.

In order to use transactions, you need a **MongoDB** replica set, and starting a replica set locally for development is an involved process. The new `run-rs npm module` makes starting replica sets easy. Running run-rs is all you need to start a replica set, run-rs will even install the correct version of `MongoDB` for you.

Run-rs has no outside dependencies except `Node.js` and `npm`. You do not need to have `Docker`, `homebrew`, `APT`, `Python`, or even `MongoDB` installed.

Install run-rs globally with `npm's -g` flag. You can also list run-rs in your `package.json` file's devDependencies.

```
npm install run-rs -g
```

Next, run run-rs with the --version flag. Run-rs will download MongoDB v4.0.0 for you. Don't worry, it won't overwrite your existing MongoDB install.

```
run-rs -v 4.0.0 --shell
```

Then use **`replicaSet=rs`** in your connection string.

You find more details about it [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/introducing-run-rs-zero-config-mongodb-runner).

Comment: Also useful is the bitnami/mongodb docker image, which allows you to setup a replicaSet with docker-compose: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb#setting-up-a-replication

Comment: From the doc, it seems running an existing (or a new) `mongod` instance with replica-set is rather trivial : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

Comment: Any idea why the ability to use transactions required MongoDB replica set ? (In my case I have MongoDb instance that run on docker for tests and cannot run transactions due this following this limitation)

Comment: runnning into the same limitation as well. Tried using mongodb-memory-server but i think I just dont understand replicaSets well.

Comment: Any idea why it needs to be installed globally and not just as a dev dependency?

Comment: Please tell me that, is replica set required while hosting mongodb on cloud too or not...??

Comment: Addition to this answer I also had to apply answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729445/5549301

Comment: Why is replica set required? It makes no sense to me and seems this was a blunder on the mongodb team.

Comment: @MarcelFalliere It looks so trivial but it's designed in such way that implementing it in Docker is going to be painful. And it seems from another answer they already broke one Docker solution. Maybe they hate Docker, hate transactions or lure us to use replicas? It makes no sense and goes against whatever principles we created so far...

Comment: I got 'Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted.' I thought this was to set a local mongo db to a replica set?

Comment: Does this help with jest? https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb

Comment: Be very careful here, running `run-rs` in a non empty folder can delete or override your files. I had a data folder and it removes all my files from it.

Answer (score 34):

I got the solution, and it's just three lines configuration inside the MongoDB config file.

After switching from MongoDB atlas and installing MongoDB v 4.4.0 on my CentOS 7 VPS with WHM, I faced that issue also.

the `run-rs` solution does not work for me, but I managed to solve this issue without any third-party tool, following these steps:

#### 1. turn off `mongod`.

the most efficient way is by entering the MongoDB shell with the command `mongo`
checkout the method

```
db.shutdownServer()
```

You will be no ability to use the MongoDB server.
For me, the shutdown process took too long, and then I killed the process with the command:

```
systemctl stop -f mongod
```

if you killed the `mongod` process,s probably you will need to run
`mongod --dbpath /var/db --repair`

The `var/db` should point to your database directory.

#### 2. setting replicaSet configuration.

for the replicaSet settings step, check out the `/etc/mongod.conf` file,
look for the `replication` value line, and you should add the following lines as below:

```
replication:
   oplogSizeMB: <int>
   replSetName: <string>
   enableMajorityReadConcern: <boolean>
```

use the `replSetName` value on the next step.

an example of those settings:

```
   oplogSizeMB: 2000
   replSetName: rs0
   enableMajorityReadConcern: false
```

#### 3. add your connection string URL.

add the value of replSetName to your connection URL `&replicaSet=--YourReplicationSetName--`

if you used the name `rs0` from our example, then you should add to your DB connection URL query `replicaSet=rs0`

#### 4. turn on mongod again

enter the command: `systemctl start mongod`

#### 5. Access your replicaSet database

enter MongoDB shell with the command `mongo`, enter the command `rs.initiate()`
now you should be in your replicaSet database.

Comment: Best solution for local development in my opinion. It's really easy to do and works without any third-party software.

Comment: What value we need to give on replSetName? can you say some example

Comment: Hi @KannanT, I modified my answer and attached an example.

Comment: In case your Mongo Service cannot start after restart, follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/884541/cant-start-mongodb-service

Comment: If using MongoDB version 5 and above, exclude the `enableMajorityReadConcern: true` line for the `/etc/mongod.conf` file. Check your Mongo installation version with `mongo --version`

Comment: Link to the relevant docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication-options

Comment: In order to connect to the db after the above steps I had to set `directConnection` option in the connection string to `true`: 
`&directConnection=true`

Answer (score 20):

For those who wants to develop against of the dockerized MongoDB instance, here is the single-file `docker-compose.yaml` solution based on the official MongoDB docker image:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:5
    command: --replSet rs0
    ports:
      - "28017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: attachment-api-local-dev
    healthcheck:
      # use 'mongo' instead of 'mongosh' if MongoDB version is lower than 5
      test: mongosh --eval 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' localhost:27017/test --quiet
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5

  mongo-init:
    image: mongo:5
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      mongodb:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: >
      mongo --host mongodb:27017 --eval
      '
      rs.initiate( {
         _id : "rs0",
         members: [
            { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27017" }
         ]
      })
      '
```

A cleaner solution would be to replace the `mongo-init` container with an init-script shared as a volume:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./mongo/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

where `/mongo/init/0. mongo-init.js` is:

```js
rs.initiate()
// wait a bit for RS configuration to complete
sleep(3000)
```

---

A much easier solution is to just use [Bitnami MongoDB image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb) with `MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE` env variable:

```yaml
services:
  mongodb:
    image: bitnami/mongodb:5.0
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE: primary
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
```

But the Bitnami image only supports linux/amd64 architecture and in practice it will hang forever even if you try to run it with Rosetta Docker host. So, if you have Mac on Apple Silicon, your the only option is to use the official `mongo` image unless [bitnami/40937](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/40947) is resolved

Comment: Apparently, the `MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY` environment variable is also required. Without it, the Mongo process refused to start in the container with an error indicating the variable is mandatory. I just set it to something like `MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY: 123456`

Comment: @Boaz never had such a problem with Mongo 5. You probably use 6+

Comment: Actually, I use 4.2 :)

Comment: Thanks, the bitnami service seems to work fine for overleaf docker-compose.

Answer (score 13):

Possible solution for local development using **docker**

Create Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:4.4.7
RUN echo "rs.initiate();" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.js
CMD [ "--replSet", "rs" ]
```

Build this Dockerfile

```
docker build ./ -t mongodb:4.7-replset
```

Run this created image

```
docker run --name mongodb-replset -p 27017:27017 -d mongodb:4.7-replset
```

Connect to database using this URI

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB
```

Comment: The suggested solution does not work for MongoDB 5.0.5 because of "MongoServerError: command replSetInitiate requires authentication" (docker-entrypoint.sh does not invoke `mongo` with user and password, also it does not print the error, you can only see it if `mongo` is replaced with `mongosh`). Aside from that you need `CMD ["--replSet", "rs", "--keyFile", "/etc/mongodb.key"]`

Comment: Even with this work around
`RUN echo 'rs.initiate();' > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.script
RUN echo 'mongosh -u "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" -p "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.script' > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.sh
`

we get `MongoServerError: This node was not started with the replSet option`.

It is simply because `docker-entrypoint.sh` is not designed to run replicas. Actually, it looks like it is designed not to run them. See `# remove "--auth" and "--replSet" for our initial startup` in the source code

Comment: Here is related breaking change: https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/211#issuecomment-344347819

Comment: If anyone interested see scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh.patch and Dockerfile in https://github.com/thenewboston-developers/Node/pull/69 for workaround/solution

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue recently. In my case it's because I'm connecting to a remote Mongo server with a different version than my local development environment.

To quickly solve the issue, I added the following param to my connection string:

> ?**retryWrites=false**

Comment: This looks rather suspicious. Are you sure it doesn't just make all errors silent instead of fixing them? Why is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 7):

When running MongoDB on a Linux Machine, you can simply use replication by updating connection string via editing service file

```
/usr/lib/mongod.service   or   /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

and update it with following

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config "/etc/mongod.conf" --replSet rs0
```

where `--config "/etc/mongod.conf"` is pointing to your MongoDB Configuration file and `--replSet rs0` is telling it to use replication with the name of `rs0`

and then restart

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload     //<--To reload service units
sudo systemctl restart mongod    //<--To Restart MongoDB Server
```

and then initiate replication through your mongod instance in terminal

```
$ mongosh
$ rs.initiate()
```

Comment: This was the only that work for me. I have a little question, if I start a connection with mongoose like this: mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name   do I need to add something relate with replicaSet. I mean, I've started to make some test and this works perfect only with this without replicaSet in the URL, but I don't know if this could cause problems later.

Comment: @Luis It would be better if you tell mongoose or any other connection by including `?replicaSet=rs0`. Whenever I connect through PHP or any other connection, I always do so.

Comment: Something strange happened today. I was presented with the replica set error again (which I had solved a long time ago). I don't know why, but that configuration was deleted. I had to add it back. Is this related to mongo updates?

Comment: @Luis yes it can be highly related to your Linux auto updates. If you have not configured your update settings then mongodb will probably get updated and so its following files. I have witnessed the same for PHP and Nginx etc

Answer (score 3):

In order to use transactions, you need a MongoDB replica set, and starting a replica set locally for development is an involved process.

You can use the `run-rs npm module`. Zero-config MongoDB runner. Starts a replica set with no non-Node dependencies, not even MongoDB.

Or you can simply create an account in `MongoDB Atlas` which gives you a limited resource MongoDB cluster and so you can run/test your application.

[MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas)

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking for a proper `docker-compose.yml` for testing with MongoDB replica set initialized, try this, which also works with the latest official MongoDB image (7):

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:7
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    command: mongod --replSet rs0
    healthcheck:
      test: |
        mongosh --eval "try { rs.status().ok } catch (e) { rs.initiate({ _id: 'rs0', members: [{ _id: 0, host: 'localhost:27017' }] }).ok }"
      start_period: 0s
      interval: 500ms
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

This will initialize a replica set on one of the first health checks.

Comment: What an ingenious solution!!! This is the solution you are looking for, guys! Thanks, @nikitaeverywhere :)

Answer (score 1):

Works for `mongo:5.0.5-focal` image.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:5.0.5-focal AS rs-mongo

# Make MongoDB a replica set to support transactions. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/68621185/1952977
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install patch

# How to create scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh.patch
# 1. Download the original file:
#    wget https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/raw/master/5.0/docker-entrypoint.sh
#    ( wget https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/raw/b5c0cd58cb5626fee4d963ce05ba4d9026deb265/5.0/docker-entrypoint.sh )
# 2. Make a copy of it:
#    cp docker-entrypoint.sh docker-entrypoint-patched.sh
# 3. Add required modifications to docker-entrypoint-patched.sh
# 4. Create patch:
#    diff -u docker-entrypoint.sh docker-entrypoint-patched.sh > scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh.patch
# 5. Clean up:
#    rm docker-entrypoint.sh docker-entrypoint-patched.sh
COPY scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh.patch .
RUN patch /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh docker-entrypoint.sh.patch
RUN mkdir -p /etc/mongo-key && chown mongodb:mongodb /etc/mongo-key

CMD ["--replSet", "rs", "--keyFile", "/etc/mongo-key/mongodb.key"]
```

scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh.patch:

```
--- docker-entrypoint.sh    2022-01-04 15:35:19.594435819 +0300
+++ docker-entrypoint-patched.sh    2022-01-06 10:16:26.285394681 +0300
@@ -288,6 +288,10 @@
    fi

    if [ -n "$shouldPerformInitdb" ]; then
+
+     openssl rand -base64 756 > /etc/mongo-key/mongodb.key
+    chmod 400 /etc/mongo-key/mongodb.key
+
        mongodHackedArgs=( "$@" )
        if _parse_config "$@"; then
            _mongod_hack_ensure_arg_val --config "$tempConfigFile" "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}"
@@ -408,7 +412,14 @@
        set -- "$@" --bind_ip_all
    fi

-   unset "${!MONGO_INITDB_@}"
+  echo 'Initiating replica set'
+  "$@" --logpath "/proc/$$/fd/1" --fork
+  echo 'rs.initiate({"_id":"rs","members":[{"_id":0,"host":"127.0.0.1:27017"}]});' | mongosh -u "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" -p "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD"
+  "$@" --logpath "/proc/$$/fd/1" --shutdown
+  echo 'Done initiating replica set'
+
+  unset "${!MONGO_INITDB_@}"
+
 fi

 rm -f "$jsonConfigFile" "$tempConfigFile"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mongo:
    image: rs-mongo:current
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db
      - mongo-configdb:/data/configdb
      - mongo-key:/etc/mongo-key

volumes:
  mongo-db:
    driver: local
  mongo-configdb:
    driver: local
  mongo-key:
    driver: local
```

**UPDATED:** 6th of Jan, 2022

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting against this issue for weeks. I let you my conclusion. 
In order to be able to use transactions on a sharded cluster, you need to run at least MongoDB 4.2 on your cluster. If the cluster is not sharded, from 4.0.
I was using a library that has as a sub-dependency mongodb NodeJS driver. This driver from version 3.3.x fails against the sharded MongoDB cluster with version 4.0.4. 
The solution for me was to update my cluster to 4.2 version.

src: https://www.bmc.com/blogs/mongodb-transactions/

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are using MongoDB sessions and it is not configured on your system.

run this to install run-rs :-

```
npm install run-rs -g
```

run:-

```
run-rs -v 4.0.0 --shell
```

You should see the below output. Please be patient since MongoDB 4.0.0 is about 70MB.

```
$ run-rs -v 4.0.0 --shell
Downloading MongoDB 4.0.0
Copied MongoDB 4.0.0 to '/home/node/lib/node_modules/run-rs/4.0.0'
Purging database...
Running '/home/node/lib/node_modules/run-rs/4.0.0/mongod'
Starting replica set...
Started replica set on "mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019"
Running mongo shell: /home/node/lib/node_modules/run-rs/4.0.0/mongo
rs:PRIMARY>
```

You now have a replica set running MongoDB 4.0.0 locally. Run rs.status() to verify the replica set is running.

NOTE:- Your nodejs version should be $gte v3.1.0

Answer (score -1):

com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 20 and error message 'Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos'

I am facing this issue on SpringBoot microservice with mongoDB using with Transaction

Solution:

Transactions are not allowed on local running mongo, Remove Transactional annotation from service method on local run