# Transaction with mongoose (Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First, can someone please clarify this for me about `replica set`: does this mean I can't ran `transactions` on a single server(simply, without some VM etc) in production? Do I need to use `run-rs` for this? Please explain.

I ran the `npm install run-rs -g` and then `run-rs -v 4.0.0`, I've received a hanging response with `Started replica set...` and `Connected to oplog`. But when I try to send a request(in relevant endpoint) I receive an error: `Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos`

I connect like so:

```
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/my-db-name", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
```

I use node with mongoose(5+)

Comment: Right, standalones are not acceptable for transactions because they do not have an oplog.

Comment: This can be helpful for you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461952/mongodb-v4-0-transaction-mongoerror-transaction-numbers-are-only-allowed-on-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461952/mongodb-v4-0-transaction-mongoerror-transaction-numbers-are-only-allowed-on-a)