# How to start a transaction in MongoDb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

I'm trying to prevent concurrent requests to a specific record, see the following example:

```
function addMoney(orderID,orderID){
    const status = Database.getOrder(orderID);

    if (status === 1){
        return "Money Already Added";
    }

    Database.udateOrder(orderID, {status: 1});

    Database.addMoney(userID, 300);

    return true;
}
```

Assume someone made this request exactly at the same time, therefore the "status" check passed, they'd be able to get `Database.addMoney` run twice.

Using MySQL, I'd start a transction to lock the row but not sure how to do so using MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the transactions in mongodb like MySQL. Consider having an `order` document with `id:123` and `status:0`. Then you can check for status in a transaction and return if it's already paid or fall through in order to add money document and update order status.
If you face any issue like `Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos` [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461952/mongodb-v4-0-transaction-mongoerror-transaction-numbers-are-only-allowed-on-a) might help.

> In order to use transactions, you need a MongoDB replica set, and
> starting a replica set locally for development is an involved process.
> The new run-rs npm module makes starting replica sets easy.

```
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'myDB';
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

async function main() {

    const client = new MongoClient(uri);
    await client.connect();
    const session = client.startSession();
    try {
        await session.withTransaction(async () => {
            const orders = client.db(dbName).collection('orders');
            const money = client.db(dbName).collection('money');
            let doc = await orders.findOne({orderID: 123});
            if (doc && doc.status === 1) {
                console.log("Money Already Added");
                return
            }
            await orders.updateOne({orderID: 123}, {'$set': {status: 1}});
            await money.insertOne({orderID: 123, userID: 100, amount: 300}, {session});
            console.log("Money added");
        });
        await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    } finally {
        await session.endSession();
        await client.close();
    }
}

main()
```

**The code above may need improvement because I couldn't test it on MongoDB with replica set.**

Comment: Thought I'd point out that if the operations in the callback succeed, then `session.withTransaction()` automatically commits the transaction when the callback returns. So `await session.commitTransaction()` is unnecessary ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Session.withTransaction/)).