# MongoDB transactions implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got this code that uses **express** and **mongodb(mongoose)** to store liked animations in **db**, the user has the ability to like/dislike animations so I need to implement **transactions**:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./login').User;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animationsdb');

router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    // implement transaction
    try {
        const result = await User.findOne({ username: req.query.username });
        if (result) {
            console.log("Liked animations:", result.likedAnimations);
            res.send({ animationList: result.likedAnimations });
        } else {
            console.log("no database result found");
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

I need help imlementing the transactions, I tried this way:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./login').User;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animationsdb');

router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    // implement transactions
    try {
        const session = await mongoose.startSession();
        session.startTransaction();
        const result = await User.findOne({ username: req.query.username }).session(session);
        if (result) {
            console.log("Liked animations:", result.likedAnimations);
            res.send({ animationList: result.likedAnimations });
        } else {
            console.log("no database result found");
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
        await session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

But it does'nt work.
Also I tried adding `?replicaSet=rs` in connection string and `?retryWrites=false` and installing

```
npm install run-rs -g
```

but none of it worked

Comment: It's a GET operation, why do you need a transaction there?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the response outside of your session. After `await session.commitTransaction();`
Also try out the solution from this question [Mongodb v4.0 Transaction, MongoError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461952/mongodb-v4-0-transaction-mongoerror-transaction-numbers-are-only-allowed-on-a)

Do NOT use localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the host name in your connection string if you use Windows, use *computer name* instead and add `?replicaSet=rs` at the end. `rs` is the name of the replica set.

Also don't forget to add `&retryWrites=false` to your connection string.

Use `run-rs -v 4.0.0` to start a replica set.

Comment: I get this error again:
```
GET /animation-list/?username=marko 500 6.382 ms - 21
MongoError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos
```

Comment: Are you connected to a mongodb Atlas cluster?

Comment: I am on local host `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animationsdb');`

Comment: I edited my answer. There seem to be a good solution at the link I posted above.

Comment: I also tried solution you posted now, but it's not working for me