# Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected-springboot-mongodb-transactions

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, transactions, mongotemplate

I got a requirement to work with spring mongotemplate transactions.
unless criteria meets,will have to roll back the transaction manually.
I am getting exception like
com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected.
How to work with Spring mongodb transactions.
Please help me out.

```
@Autowired
MongoTransactionManager mongoTransactionManager;

@Autowired
TestDao testDao;

@Transactional
public void testMethod() {
    int temp = 0;
    try {
        testDao.saveDatainTempTable();
        testDao.saveMongoData();
        if (temp == 0) {
            System.out.println("=========================");
            TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
            mongoTransactionManager.rollback(TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

@Configuration
public class MongoTransactionConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDbFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider updating the server side Mongo client to a version that does support sessions.

Comment: I am using the updated version only mongo v4.0.9 which supports sessions.But Still I am getting exception.I don't understand where I am going wrong

Comment: I have a similar issue using monogdb server 4.0.9

Comment: @naaz Please let me know if you find any solution

Comment: I was told that in my case it doesn't work with single instances

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255195/how-to-configure-a-mongodb-cluster-which-supports-sessions

Answer (score 1):

- On Linux, a default /etc/mongod.conf configuration file is included
  when using a package manager to install MongoDB.
- On Windows, a
  default <install directory>/bin/mongod.cfg configuration file is
  included during the installation
- On macOS, a default /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf configuration file is included
  when installing from MongoDB’s official Homebrew tap.

**Add** the following config

```
replication:
   oplogSizeMB: 128
   replSetName: "rs0"
   enableMajorityReadConcern: true
```

**sudo service mongod restart;**

**mongo;**

```
rs.initiate({
      _id: "rs0",
      version: 1,
      members: [
         { _id: 0, host : "localhost:27017" }
      ]
   }
)
```

**check** for the config to be enabled

```
rs.conf()
```

we can use the **connection URL** as

```
mongodb://localhost/default?ssl=false&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=primary
```

docs: [config-options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) [single-instance-replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/)